# PowerBI DAX how to exclude blanks from weighted average

Tags: powerbi, dax, weighted-average

I can build the weighted average via quick measure

```
Average of columnA weighted by weight per Id = 
VAR __CATEGORY_VALUES = VALUES('table'[Id])
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX(
            KEEPFILTERS(__CATEGORY_VALUES),
            CALCULATE(AVERAGE('table'[columnA]) * SUM('table'[weight]))
        ),
        SUMX(KEEPFILTERS(__CATEGORY_VALUES), CALCULATE(SUM('table'[weight])))
    )
```

But my columnA has some blanks. How can I exclude these blanks from the weighted average?

Comment: Would AVERAGEA work in this case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/averagea-function-dax

Comment: No. But replacing the second KEEPFILTERS with 
`FILTER('table', NOT(ISBLANK('table'[columnA])))`
worked